# how to make color cover the background color?

Tags: react-native, opacity

I tried `rgba(156, 39, 176, 1)` but it does not cover the color under it.
How can I make the purple color circle cover the part of background bell?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try setting `zIndex` on the badge to make it render on top. However Android has some `zIndex` issues, so if that doesn't work then you have to render it after. So you have this right now:

```
<View>
   <Badge>
   <Image>
</View>
```

You need to do:

```
<View>
   <Image>
   <Badge>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-icon-badge](https://github.com/yanqiw/react-native-icon-badge) to create this notification icon symbol with count.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <IconBadge
    MainElement={
      <View>
        <Image
          style={{width:60,height:60,margin:3}}
          source={bell}
        />
      </View>
    }
    BadgeElement={
      <Text style={{color:'#FFFFFF'}}>3</Text>
    }
    IconBadgeStyle={
      {width:30,
      height:30,
      backgroundColor: '#9c27b0'}
    }
    Hidden={this.state.BadgeCount==0}
    />
</View>
```